# Plot Optimal Decision variable and Corresponding Residuals

Tags: matlab, convex-optimization, cvx

I have this matlab cvx setup for my problem to estimate least squares solution

```
n = 100;
A = randn(14,n);
b = randn(14,1);
cvx_begin
variable x(n)
   minimize( norm( A*x-b ) 
   cvx_end

echo off
```

As Cvx shows the optimal value after running i do not know how i can generate the plot of optimal decision value and residuals

Comment: I cannot run your example in matlab, cvx_begin and cvx_end are undefined.

Comment: yes i guess you don not have cvx setup at the moment